# Zorba "context item" undeclared variable error

Tags: zorba

I downloaded the file called standard and renamed it as auction.xml from the following website [Link to file](http://www.ins.cwi.nl/projects/xmark/Assets/standard.gz)

I wrote an insert query and stored in a file called insertqz.xq

```
for $doc in doc('auction.xml')/site/open_auctions//bidder/increase
return insert node <watch open_auction='open_auction5104'/> before $doc
```

and run the following command : `zorba -t -q insertqz.xq`

I get the following error: `(no URI):1,2: dynamic error [err:XPDY0002]: "context item": undeclared variable`

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove -q

`zorba -t insertqz.xq`

to print the updated xml file:

`for $doc in doc("auction.xml")/site/open_auctions//bidder/increase
return insert node <watch open_auction="open_auction5104"/> before $doc;
doc("auction.xml")`